# Halogenation by Phosphorous tribromide vs using HBr

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, alcohols, halogenation

My textbook introduced $\ce{PBr3}$ by stating that it leads to an inversion in stereochemistry since it always goes through an S<sub>N</sub>2 pathway, unlike using $\ce{HBr}$.

My question is that since $\ce{Br-}$ is a reasonably good nucleophile, so I assume it would most likely proceed through S<sub>N</sub>2 in a substrate with a secondary carbon anyway. Both pathways seem to me to be extremely similar with the exact same attacking species eventually ($\ce{Br-}$) and an excellent modified leaving group attached ($\ce{H3O+}$ and $\ce{OHPBr2}$).

What exactly is the difference and the advantage (other than being non-acidic) that make halogenation by $\ce{PBr3}$ a better method?

Comment: HBr can give rise to great amounts of alkene through elimination due to the SN1 pathway with secondary alsohols.

Comment: How would this be avoided when using PBr3?

Comment: There is no SN1 pathway with PBr3

Answer (score 1):

The problem with $\ce{HBr}$ is that it can almost always cause an S<sub>N</sub>1 reaction, even if the alcohol is primary.

Consider the reaction of propanol with $\ce{HBr}$. Even though the resulting leaving group would make a primary carbocation if it left on its own, this can be avoided via a concerted rearrangement, thus making it possible for an S<sub>N</sub>1 reaction to happen. This doesn't happen with $\ce{PBr3}$ of its difference in mechanism.

[image]

Comment: If, as your mechanism shows, the reaction is concerted, then there is no primary carbocation formed. Is this true?

Comment: Yes, which is what makes the SN1 reaction viable even for primary carbocations. I'm not exactly sure why (since the LG is good in the PBr3 reaction), but Solomons & Fryhle 10th edition mentions "The reaction of an alcohol with PBr3 does not involve formation of a carbocation and usually occurs without rearrangement of the carbon skeleton" in chapter 11.9, which means that it wouldn't have issues of potential concerted rearrangements.

Comment: Your diagram shows HBr, not $\ce{PBr3}$
. I'd be surprised if a primary alcohol didn't give a primary bromide with $\ce{PBr3}$, i.e., an $\ce{SN2}$ reaction. But with HBr, you show the rearrangement as a concerted hydride shift, indicating no intermediary primary carbocation

Comment: I believe I was unclear with my wording. I am trying to convey that the water group leaving on its own does not involve the concerted rearrangement (and would thus result in a primary carbocation), but because the concerted rearrangement happens, the formation of a primary carbocation is avoided entirely. Hopefully my edit better reflects this.